# Nginx fastcgi_cache not working for one WP site (but working OK for time.php on different vhost)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

I am running Ubuntu nginx 1.8 with fpm php 5.5, on one site I am able to get cache working (with a simple time output) `<?php echo time();?>` shows:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 08 Jan 2016 14:04:00 GMT
Fastcgi-Cache:HIT
Server:nginx/1.8.0
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
```

But for the WordPress site the headers always show (even when logged out and incognito):

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 08 Jan 2016 14:02:42 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Fastcgi-Cache:BYPASS
Link:<http://mywpsite.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link:<http://mywpsite.com/>; rel=shortlink
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.8.0
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
```

From the wiki i have tried different settings and compressed down to the following individual files (tester.com works, whereas mywpsite.com does not - these are aliases i have set in my hostfile and definitely hitting the right server) https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx.

**cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP.
        upstream php {
                #this should match value of "listen" directive in php-fpm pool
                server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
}
```

**cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/tester.com**

```
fastcgi_cache_path /home/tester.com/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name tester.com;

    root /home/tester.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
    }
}
```

**cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/mywpsite.com**

```
fastcgi_cache_path /home/mywpsite.com/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYWPSITE:100m inactive=60m;

server {
        server_name mywpsite.com;
        root /home/mywpsite.com/public_html;

        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                deny all;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

        set $skip_cache 0;

        if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        if ($query_string != "") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
               access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }

        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache MYWPSITE;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                        return 404;
                }
                # This is a robust solution for path info security issue and works with "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" in /etc/php.ini (default)

                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                #       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;

                fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
                fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

                fastcgi_cache MYWPSITE;
                fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
        }

        location ~ /purge(/.*) {
                fastcgi_cache_purge MYWPSITE"$scheme$request_method$host$1";
        }
}
```

Apologies as I am sure it is something stupid, but after a number of late nights would appreciate some fresh eyes going over this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have things split between your config files in a weird way. It makes no difference to nginx but it makes it much more difficult for a person to read.

Here's my reasonably well documented working config for a tutorial I'm going to post at some point - I suspect the fastcgi_ignore_headers may help. I have this at the top of a single site file, but it could go into nginx.conf. Check your file permissions, I don't think it's that but it's really important for any process that clears the cache - that part is quite tricky.

```
# Caching. Putting the cache into /dev/shm keeps it in RAM, limited to 10MB, for one day. Or put it into a more standard /etc/nginx/cache
# You can move to disk if you like, or extend the caching time
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:10m inactive=1440m; #Disk
#fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/nginxcache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:10m inactive=1440m; #RAM

# This is to do with how the files are laid out on disk
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

# Determines in which cases a stale cached response can be used when an error occurs during communication with the FastCGI server
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;

# Wordpress themes (especially Photocrati) often send back inappropriate headers, so ignore them
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie ;

# Rules to work out when cache should/shouldn't be used
set $skip_cache 0;
# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

Here's my location block. Note that I use the HHVM PHP interpreter written by Facebook, it's faster and more efficient than PHP5, and PHP7 doesn't work with my Wordpress theme Photocrati

```
  # Send HipHop and PHP requests to HHVM
  location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
  fastcgi_keep_conn on;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  fastcgi_pass   php;
  include            fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

  # Use the cache defined above. Cache only 200 (success) status's, for 24 hours
  # Only cache GET and HEAD requests
  fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
  fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1440m;
  add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

  fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
  fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
  fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

  # Clear the server ID, for security. Clear the cache control headers. 
  more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Pragma";

  # Add cache control headers that say each page is valid for an hour
  add_header Z_LOCATION "PHP MAIN"; add_header URI $uri; # DEBUG
  }
```

Then inside each location block put the following to help debug what's going on - it will tell you the variables and the location block in use which will help you debug. Use Firefox and the plugin "Live HTTP Headers" to see the output

```
add_header Z_LOCATION "(name of your location block)"; # DEBUG
add_header Z_URI $uri; # DEBUG
add_header Z_CACHE $skip_cache; # DEBUG
add_header URI $uri; # DEBUG
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I would very much like to read your tutorial. Any points on how to have multiple WordPress sites, same as above for each file? Presume would use a different key_zone for each site? Also if one had a lot of RAM (say 64GB) a RAM cache of 1GB would be sufficient or overkill? It you could post a full file it would be appreciated and will mark as answered, keen to see how you pass on to the PHP-FPM process (and securely, as understand there as some security issues if not done correctly)?

Comment: Tutorial will be ready in a few weeks. You use Wordpress Multisite, restriction is blogs can't be on a subfolder of the target domain - eg example.com/blog . Prefer not to share my full config until finished and edited for privacy / security, but happy to share blocks - let me know what you need. I use hhvm not regular PHP, it's faster. I'm running all this on a server with 1GB of RAM and a 10MB nginx RAM page cache, an AWS t2.micro, low traffic sites mostly. Will update my answer above with parts of my config related to php in a minute.

Comment: @g18c keep an eye on my website if you want to see the tutorial. It's fairly substantial, six parts each quite large in itself, and will be a few weeks give or take. https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/blog/

Comment: Thanks Tim, I prefer to keep the wordpress instances (and key_zone caches) totally separate if at all possible.

Comment: Sure, makes little difference, you just define multiple caches.

Comment: I was just wondering how you got on with the tutorial? :)

Comment: Another 2-3 weeks I think, just watch the blog.

Comment: Thisi one dit it for me: "Wordpress themes (especially Photocrati) often send back inappropriate headers"